# Applying for PhD after Engineering work on MS

Tags: phd, application

I'm considering revisiting a PhD, my last MS I felt I basically spent my time on engineering work the advisor needed to get done vs actual research. I was effectively an engineer working for a small salary without help.

I don't think what I ended up doing for my MS was particularly useful from the perspective of research and my advisor basically offered zero help.

When applying to PhD programs at other universities how should I address this?

I graduated from every program I entered, generally good theoretical understanding of topics and a high GPA but I don't have any publications because of the above.

I also felt my role was just researchy enough to not really count as true engineering experience because of how hackey I had to approach problems since I was doing it solo, under limited time.

Comment: Could you edit the question to specify 1) what you mean by MS (manuscript, masters?), and 2) what is the question that you’re asking: is it about how to get into a PhD program with no publications, or no research experience? Or something else?

Comment: I imagine most folks entering a PhD program have no publications.

Comment: What country or countries are you applying in?

Comment: Only the US ...

Comment: Welcome to the early stages of research in an experimental field. I’d say you did well. Stop worrying about it.